# Comparison between quantities of several things

Tags: grammar, comparative-constructions, comparative, academic-writing

For academic writing, which of these three comparative styles is preferred, or more correct?

1. The mantle velocity of the China Craton is around 8 Km/s, similar to the typical cratons.
2. The mantle velocity of the China Craton is around 8 Km/s, similar to those of the typical cratons.
3. The mantle velocity of the China Craton is around 8 Km/s, similar to the ones obtained for the typical cratons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic structure you are trying to use has three elements: velocity, Km/s, and cratons.  You can only use the structure you propose if you compare things of the same kind: i.e., velocity X with velocity Y, X Km/s with Y Km/s, and X craton with Y craton.

Your main comparison is actually velocity X with velocity Y and the rest is just descriptive material to differentiate X from Y.  I would propose one of the following possibilities:

1. The mantle velocity of the China Craton is around 8 Km/s, similar to that of typical cratons.
2. The mantle velocity of the China Craton is around 8 Km/s, similar to the case of typical cratons.
3. The mantle velocity of the China Craton is around 8 Km/s, similar to the velocity of typical cratons.

In technical writing, I prefer the first option for conciseness, but I think the 3rd is actually clearest and best.  By the way, "that" must be singular to agree with "velocity," which is also singular.